# Update selected listview item in pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm using `PyQt5` and I would like to know how I can update the value of the selected items in a listview without having to delete them before, becauses it messes the ordering of the rows.

This is the code I'm using

```
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class App(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(App, self).__init__()
        self.listView.setModel(QStandardItemModel())
        self.update_btn.clicked.connect(self.update)
        self.show()
            
    def update(self):
        if len(self.listView.selectedIndexes()) > 0:
            items = self.listView.selectedIndexes()
            for item in items:
                row = item.row()
                text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Update Dialog', 'Enter new value')
                if ok:
                    self.listView.model().takeRow(row)
                    self.listView.model().appendRow(QStandardItem(text))    
        
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = App()
app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
def update(self):
    if len(self.listView.selectedIndexes()) > 0:
        indices = self.listView.selectedIndexes()
        for index in indices:
            item = self.listView.model().itemFromIndex(index)
            text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(self, 'Update Dialog', 'Enter new value')
            if ok:
                item.setText(text)
```